# Meaning of : variable <-struct {}{}

Tags: go, structure, channel

I don't understand the meaning of the double {}. This is not made clear in any learning material.  Thanks.

```
variable <-struct {}{}
```

Answer (score 7):

> I don't understand the meaning of the double {}.
>
> ```
> struct {}{}
> ```

In long form,

```
type T struct{}
var t = T{}
```

`struct {}` is a type, a `struct` with no fields, and `struct {}{}` is a composite literal, with zero values, of that type.

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

[Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

[The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)

Comment: And the reason one might use this is to send a simple indicator over a channel when no data is needed - for example, a "exit this routine" channel or a "hit counter" channel. In this case, an empty struct is the most efficient because it uses no memory.

Answer (score 1):

`variable` is a variable of type channel (values are sent on it)

`<-` is a send operator

`struct{}` is type empty struct (has no fields)

`{}` makes it a struct literal (creates a value of the given struct type)

To better understand this form let me give you an example of a different struct type:

```
p := struct{ X, Y float64 }{0.0, 0.0}
```